# Application not installed (different)

Tags: adb, root-access, 4.4-kitkat, samsung

So when I updated my Android to *4.4.2*, the default Samsung Gallery app disappeared. Now, I decided to dig into the files of the Android 4.4.2 update and extracted the system.img and found the application, named ***SecGallery2013.apk*** I copied it to my SD Card and tried to install it normally, it gave the error "Application not installed" So I tried to install it via ADB, but it gave an error **"INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED"** so I digged into my phone and found the same APK in system/priv-app and I deleted it and after that, I tried again but this time it gave the error: **"INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT"** Things I've tried:

- I got a logcat and this was the result, hope someone can understand:

> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 W/SELinuxMMAC ]
>
> assignSeinfoValue, matching key found
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 W/SELinuxMMAC ]
>
> assignSeinfoValue , step 2, pkgName:com.sec.android.gallery3d, seinfo:platform
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 W/SELinuxMMAC ]
>
> assignSeinfoValue, step 4, pkgName:com.sec.android.gallery3d, seinfo:platform
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 I/SELinuxMMAC ]
>
> com.sec.android.gallery3d registered as an RCP File Copier App.
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 D/PackageManager ]
>
> Time to scan apk: 0.638 seconds
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 W/PackageManager ]
>
> Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.sec.android.gallery3d-1.apk
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 D/PackageManager ]
>
> doPostInstall for uid{-1}
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 D/PackageManager ]
>
> delete sourFile : 
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 D/PackageManager ]
>
> delete native library directory: 
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 D/PackageManager ]
>
> + starting rerstore round-trip 1
>
>
>
>
> [ 05-19 20:02:46.951  1604: 1728 D/PackageManager ]
>
> No resotre for backup - queue post-install for 1

- I checked another place and it said error code -24, I've did every suggestion on this site and none of them worked (except for factory resetting)
- Deleted all remaining files from gallery data, didn't work

Samsung Galaxy Note II, running rooted stock android 4.4.2.

Thanks!

Comment: In an active su shell (assuming the device is rooted) try the following command: `find / -name *com.sec.android.gallery3d*` Ignoring any "not found" errors, does it find any other files or directories? If so, remove them and try side-loading the app again.

Comment: @Chahk What do you by 'active su shell' I've tried writing this to both Terminal and ADB using ADB shell but they say find not found.

Comment: In adb shell first become root by issuing `su` command, and then try the `find` command again. It's probably some left overs from the app you uninstalled, most likely in `/cache/dalvik-cache/` or `/data/dalvik-cache/`

Comment: @Chahk Done that, given root permissions, but then it says: tmp-mksh: Find: not found

Comment: Hmm...  try "busybox find" instead.  [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) can be installed from Play Store.

Comment: @Chahk  It's no use, it says: 'tmp-mksh: busybox: not found.

Comment: I think I have busybox installed, but, I'll check it again in the program, downloading.

Comment: @Chahk When I press install in busybox, it says "An error occurred while trying to install Busybox, try restarting the application and try again or you can email me." :/ EDIT: I have Linux Ubuntu 12.04 so if you need me to manually install it, I'm ready.

Comment: Do any other commands work such as `ls`?  Can you try `ls /data/dalvik-cache/ | grep 'gallery3d'`

Comment: @Chahk Writing the ls alone will give a list of commands, but when I write ls /data/dalvik-cache/ | grep 'gallery3d' it returns the same code you gave me.

Comment: Putting the issues with busybox and other Linux commands aside, can you get the output of `ls /data/dalvik-cache/` and see if you can find any files or directories that have "gallery3d" in their name?  it should looks something like `data@app@com.sec.android.gallery3d-1@classes.dex`

Comment: @Chahk Okay I installed Busybox through another program and used your original 'find' command and it worked. :S weird.

Comment: @Chahk I'm currently using your command and locating and deleting the leftovers, will inform you if it works.

Comment: @Chahk Tried to install via ADB, INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this.

## What I did

- I did a double factory reset: Nothing happened.
- Downgraded to Android 4.2.2: Nothing happened.
- Downgraded to Android 4.1.2: Nothing happened.
- Upgraded to Android 4.3: Nothing happened.
- Factory Reset: Gallery appeared!
- Upgraded to Android 4.4.2: Gallery didn't disappear!